# Is it possible to have interface and domain objects in one solution and the implementation in another solution, in wcf service?

Tags: wcf

Is it possible to declare an interface of a WCF service and domain objects in one solution, and in a client solution can we implement it's functionality? (geographically it is a different solution). If possible, what technology should I adhere to? Should I go for REST service?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can have the Interface and DataObjects in one solution, and implement the interface in another solution (this will be the one that actually contains the WCF service).

If you do it this way, you can have the client of the WCF service (if you're in control of it) reference the assembly containing the interface and objects.That way it doesn't need to generate them.

This is a standard way of doing WCF and is independent of the binding used.

Comment: How would you address the problem I mention in my answer?

Comment: @Peladao I don't understand your answer, since AFAIK he's talking about the interface definition of the service, not returning an interface from a method on the service.

Comment: I was assuming that the interface solution also contains interfaces for types of domain objects that are used by the service methods but perhaps that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you use separate interface and implementation projects/solutions (and if the interface project also contains interfaces of objects that are used by the service methods) then the WCF service interfaces should not be part of the interface project but be defined in the implementation project.

The reason for this is that WCF service operations should not use interface types in their method signatures because interface types can not be serialized (in an interoperable way). They should use implementation types and therefore they should be part of the implementation project, because otherwise you would need to add a reference from your interface project to your implementation project. That would be poor design and would make the separation of interface from implementation useless.